# Activity Button not listening

Tags: android, button, android-activity, fragment, onclicklistener

I am new to android development and created a small application that I am stuck with.

I created an activity with layout activity_main and is inflated with MainActivity.java.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startFragment = new StartFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.dynamic_view, startFragment).commit();
    setupOnClickListeners();
}

private void setupOnClickListeners() {
    settingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad);


    settingsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View clickView) {
    switch (clickView.getId()) {
        case R.id.keypad: // select audio button
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Start");
            if (startFragment == null) {
                startFragment = new StartFragment();
            }
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.dynamic_view, startFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.settings:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Settings dialpad");
            if (settingsFragment == null) {
                settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            }
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.dynamic_view, settingsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

Once I have inflated the Settings Fragment I am not able to re-inflate the Start Fragment, in the debug logs I find that the click comes through but doesn't land on the listener.

```
10-10 02:52:24.418 30630-30630/com.avaya.ihg    
D/ViewRootImpl@bcd8f38[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-10 02:52:24.496 30630-30630/com.avaya.ihg 
D/ViewRootImpl@bcd8f38[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
```

Any Points that could help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The log you posted doesn't looks like the log of the error. Please post your entire logcat or any error that is is showing. What you posted is a debug log.

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at your code seems a bit confusing to me (not sure if you have paraphrased it?), specifically the way you are setting the listeners.

From the documentation of Button you should be setting listeners similar to this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
     }
```

From your code it looks like you are setting the listeners to your MainActivity which should give you an error.

If this is the case, using your onClick() function you would want to set the listener something like this:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MainActivity.this.onClick(v);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library? 
you can set onClick event to differents views... for example:

```
@OnClick({ R.id.door1, R.id.door2, R.id.door3 })
public void pickDoor(View view) {
  if (view.getId() == R.id.door1) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "door1", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.door2){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Try again", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    .....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened but it worked after closing the studio and doing a full clean and rerun on the device.